# Saving multiple bits of data to be later retrieved on demand?

Tags: java, android

Trying to make an app in android studio that works as a fitness helper/tracker. On a daily basis and multiple times a day, the user enters data regarding their diet/exercise. Prior to doing so, the user selects which day they're currently on, making the data they input specific to the chosen date. I want to give users the ability to retrieve any available data for a specific day on demand.

I don't quite think sharedPreferences would work, so I was thinking about just saving to internal storage as a text file. The problem is that 1) with all the different files that would be created for even a single day, I feel that it would get messy and 2) I'm not sure how how to retrieve the specific file I'd need, parse it, then output the parsed data graphically if I'm only using a single constructor to make each text file.

I haven't yet delved deeply into using a SQLite DB, it seemed somewhat excessive for this, so I'm hoping someone can either help me figure out a better way to solve the problem or enlighten me as to a more efficient method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a thought, you can try to add all relevant data for a single day as comma seperated key/value pairs, so that this file has one row per day. Then you can retrieve and parse it as needed.

Comment: I'd bite the bullet now, and it will especially help in the future, should you choose to enhance your application (offering analysis using the data, giving the option to store on your server, etc).

Comment: @Isiva the problem I see with that is that the users have optional choices for meals, meaning they could skip a snack or have an extra one. With the volatility of the entries, wouldn't it not be possible to accurately parse the data if I put each day on a single line?